# Change the normal search bar to below image like search bar

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uisearchbar, ibdesignable

Here I Just placed one search bar controller which default design in Xcode. Can any will help me to make search bar likes the second one?

**Default**

[image]

**Expected output/UI Design**

[image]

Here I have attached my own UITextField design it's may help you to solve this problem: [Github](https://github.com/pranavansp/SPTextField)

Comment: Why not use just a text field, styled and positioned properly, and not try to modify a search bar?

Comment: I need it in the search bar. can't we implement in the search bar?

Comment: That screenshot looks like a table header view. You can add the text filed there. The `UISearchBar` has a look and feel, which is hard if not impossible to modify to your hearts content. If you are heavily modifying the skin of the bar, it might as well not be a `UISearchBar`. This approach will help you maintain a cleaner code base.

Comment: What feature of a search bar are you looking to use, which would make the text field option not viable?

Comment: nope. It's fine to use UITextField

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: If u r satisfy with this, kindly accept and up vote it.

Comment: Kindly give tick mark. So will helpful for SO followers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your question by adding `UISearchBar` to `UINavigationBar`.

**Customising :**

```
@IBOutlet weak var BGView: UIView! //CONSTRAINTS top, left and right = 0, height = 64
@IBOutlet var topSearchBarr: UISearchBar!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .clear


    let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    //Set the two colors of your gradient
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.purple.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor]
    //Set it's location
    gradient.locations = [0.0 , 1.0]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width:   self.view.frame.size.width, height: 64)

    BGView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    getSearchBarSubViews()
}

func getSearchBarSubViews()
{
    let navSubVws = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews

    for subVws in navSubVws!
    {
        if (String(describing: subVws).range(of:"UINavigationBarContentView") != nil)
        {
            let barContentSubVws = subVws.subviews

            for subVws in barContentSubVws
            {
                if (String(describing: subVws).range(of:"UISearchBar") != nil)
                {
                    let searchbarVws = subVws.subviews

                    for subVws in searchbarVws
                    {
                        if (String(describing: subVws).range(of:"UIView") != nil)
                        {
                            let searchbarTopSubVws = subVws.subviews

                            for subVws in searchbarTopSubVws
                            {
                                if (String(describing: subVws).range(of:"UISearchBarTextField") != nil)
                                {
                                    let searchBarVw = subVws as! UITextField
                                    let searchbarTxtFldSubVws = subVws.subviews

                                    (subVws as! UITextField).backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0)
                                    (subVws as! UITextField).tintColor = UIColor.white
                                    (subVws as! UITextField).textColor = UIColor.white
                                    (subVws as! UITextField).clearButtonMode = .never


                                    for subVws in searchbarTxtFldSubVws
                                    {
                                        if (String(describing: subVws).range(of:"UISearchBarTextFieldLabel") != nil)
                                        {
                                            (subVws as! UILabel).textColor = UIColor.white
                                        }

                                        if (String(describing: subVws).range(of:"UIImageView") != nil)
                                        {
                                            var searchIconImgVw = (subVws as! UIImageView)

                                            searchIconImgVw.image = searchIconImgVw.image!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
                                            searchIconImgVw.tintColor = UIColor.white

                                            searchBarVw.leftViewMode = .never
                                            searchBarVw.rightView = searchIconImgVw
                                            searchBarVw.rightViewMode = .always

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }

}
```

**Storyboard**

[image]

**Output 1**

[image]

**Output 2**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop a textfield on your view controller.

Create border beneath the textfield. Here is an example code for border

```
let border = CALayer()
let width = CGFloat(2.0)
border.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textField.frame.size.height - width, 
width:  textField.frame.size.width, height: 
textField.frame.size.height)
border.borderWidth = width
textField.layer.addSublayer(border)
textField.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Create right view on textfield and search icon image. Suppose the name of your textfield is txtSearch

```
txtSearch.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
//Textfields has right and left view. While are by default off. 
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)) // Define size of the imageView you want.
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
imageView.image = UIImageView(named: "SearchIcon")
imageView.tintColor = UIColor.white 
txtSearch.rightViewMode = imageView // Put your imageView in rightViewMode.
```

Comment: I need to modify search bar, not UITextField however thanks for ur answer.

Comment: oh ok. Create a subclass of searchbar and customize it.
Follow this tutorial 
https://www.appcoda.com/custom-search-bar-tutorial/